# Merge several json picking the odd one for each value in Python

Tags: python, json

I currently have N json input files that all have the same structure, but where N - 1 values are defined as "None" for each of them. I want to combine them into a single json where, much like a git merge/patch, it always picks the set value (ie, the one different from "None"). Here is an example (fictious):

```
json 1: {'a': 'aaa', ['b': 'None', 'c': 'None']}
json 2: {'a': 'None', ['b': 'bbb', 'c': 'None']}
json 3: {'a': 'None', ['b': 'None', 'c': 'ccc']}
```

expected result: {'a': 'aaa', ['b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc']}

Atm, I'm thinking of using a zip for all the input files, iterating each word and picking whatever is not 'None' for composing the output file. However, I'm thinking there must be a cleaner way of doing it that I'm just not seeing now..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *cleaner*?

Comment: note, your example inputs *aren't even close to valid JSON.

Comment: About the json: Sorry for my mistake! What I really meant is the python scripts work with objects that looked somewhat like the examples, that later are turned into valid json's. I could work with either the objects or the json to form the desired result

By "cleaner" I meant some processing that wouldn't require explicitly iterating each file in the python code (even if it is going to be processed this way) so the code is easier to maintain (we have ~40 of that objects atm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your json files is incorrect right now. You should verify that and update the code accordingly. As of now, I have converted your json in the following format:

```
json_1 = {"a": "aaa", "b": "None", "c": "None"}
json_2 = {"a": "None", "b": "bbb", "c": "None"}
json_3 = {"a": "None", "b": "None", "c": "ccc"}
```

If the data is in files, you can use the following function:

```
import json

f = open ('data.json', "r")
json.load(f.read())
```

and if the data is in string format, you can use:

```
import json

json_1 = json.loads('{"a": "aaa", "b": "None", "c": "None"}')
json_2 = json.loads('{"a": "None", "b": "bbb", "c": "None"}')
json_3 = json.loads('{"a": "None", "b": "None", "c": "ccc"}')
```

As for the solution, iterating over the json files will be the best option. An alternate approach to solve the problem would be to clear all the keys which contain "None" beforehand and then merging them as one. The sameple code for the same is:

```
json_clean_1 = {k: v for k, v in json_1.items() if v != "None"}
json_clean_2 = {k: v for k, v in json_2.items() if v != "None"}
json_clean_3 = {k: v for k, v in json_3.items() if v != "None"}

output_json = dict(list(json_clean_1.items()) + list(json_clean_2.items()) + list(json_clean_3.items()))
print(output_json)
```

---

Based on the comment, you could use a solution similar to this. It should give you an output dataframe with a column containing the combined values:

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

# get files
json_files = [
    each_file for each_file in os.listdir(".") if each_file.endswith('.json')
]

# read files
dfs = []
for file in json_files:
    with open(file) as f:
        json_data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(f.read()))
    dfs.append(json_data)

# combine and clean df
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
cleaned_df = combined_df.replace("None", pd.NA).transpose()

# df with required column
cleaned_df['combined_col'] = cleaned_df[cleaned_df.columns].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
print(cleaned_df)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! And sorry for my mistake on the json part. To clarify a bit, we have these objects that later are transposed into valid json's, and we can work with either for this problem.
The problem is there are many more keys in each object/json, and some of them are inside lists... and we have 40+ json/objects currently, so I was hoping I could do it in fewer and more concise lines

Comment: @Nadal I have updated my solution based on this. Do let me know if this  helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I was able to modify what you provided into a working solution